# How can I restart my kombucha liquid?

Tags: kombucha

I thoughtlessly threw out the liquid of my kombuca/scoby while I was cleaning the container.

I don't believe the scoby is dead. It's not black or moldy.

The latest brew I've done, after a week, tastes like... cold tea.

Is there a way to restart the scoby/kombucha?

Comment: What temperature are you trying to ferment at? I'm a little concerned when you say "cold" tea...

Comment: As with the other answers, I would imagine the liquid is not completely crucial. But if you are following the right recipe (tea+sugar) and brewing at room temperature and still it doesn't work, you might want to try using some commercial unpasteurized Kombucha drink to give it the kick. It is now sold in most of health food shops.

Answer (score 1):

The SCOBY should act in the presence of fresh sugar, so if you are getting cold tea, then it isn't working, assuming all the conditions of time, temperature and clean vessel are met.

You can try again, dosing with a little more sugar, but if it isn't turning tea into booch then it is probably dead.

Not sure if you cultured that SCOBY or bought it, so you might need to make a new one with good booch and tea.

Also, I've heard that decaf tea is a no-no, so not sure if that entered the picture?